# Subconsultas Select

Tags: c#, sql

Meu banco esta assim:

```
cd_cliente |  nr_ddd  |   nr_telefone
30         |  11      |   25622791
30         |  11      |   25622791
```

Meu select esta assim:

```
"SELECT * FROM tb_telefones WHERE nr_ddd="+ddd+" AND nr_telefone="+telefone+"";
```

Ele retorna do banco a partir dos parâmetros ddd e telefone, os numeros que são iguais a eles.

Eu quero que a partir desse parâmetros (parametros nr_ddd e nr_telefone), ele retorne o valor de cd_cliente, e faça uma nova consulta, retornado tos os ddds e telefones que tem cd_cliente  igual.

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa. Re-leia e ajuste para que possamos te ajudar. Se possível informe a estrutura das tabelas e seja mais claro sobre o que você precisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contando que a tabela "tb_telefones" tenha as colunas que mencionou (o que faz sentido), então este select poderá lhe ajudar:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_telefones 
WHERE cd_cliente IN (SELECT cd_cliente FROM tb_telefones 
                     WHERE nr_ddd="+ddd+" 
                     AND nr_telefone="+telefone+")
```

Garanta que `ddd` e `nr_telefone` sejam inteiros e não terá problemas com o select.